# What is Scaffold? Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-bottomappbar, android-jetpack-compose-scaffold

I want to know what is Scaffold in jetpack compose with a BottomAppBar example can anyone help me
`Scaffold`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

[**`Scaffold`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#scaffold) allows you to implement a UI with the basic Material Design layout structure. `Scaffold` provides slots for the most common top-level Material components, such as `TopAppBar`, `BottomAppBar`, `FloatingActionButton`, and `Drawer`.

Something like:

```
   val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()
   // Create a coroutineScope for the animation
   val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()


    Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        drawerContent = { Text("Drawer content") },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomAppBar(cutoutShape = CircleShape) {
                IconButton(
                    onClick = {
                        coroutineScope.launch { scaffoldState.drawerState.open() }
                    }
                ) {
                    Icon(Icons.Filled.Menu, contentDescription = "....")
                }
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                text = { Text("Action") },
                onClick = { /* .... */ }
            )
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.Center,
        isFloatingActionButtonDocked = true,
        content = { innerPadding ->
            //....
        }
    )
```

[image]

Comment: scaffold is needed to create a skeleton structure on the ui side but Is scaffold always necessary? In which situations do we use or not use?

Comment: Couldn't I just use a Column with a Row, Box and Row?

Comment: Similar Question as above one.. how to make this cutout for a card? Scaffold managed this logic itself but what if we want this logic for cards in list?